# How to restart ntopng systemd?

Tags: systemd, ntop

There used to be a file in the /etc/init.d/ folder to restart ntopng.

The command that I used to use is:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntopng restart
```

But now with Ubuntu 18.04, that file is gone.

How do restart ntopng now?

Answer (score 1):

The init.d script has been converted to a systemd unit which is now located in:

`/etc/systemd/system`

You restart ntopng now by:

```
sudo systemctl restart ntopng
```

Other (most) unit files are located in:

`/lib/systemd/system/`

More information about systemd unit files by looking at the man page:

```
man systemd.unit
```

Comment: This works, but it takes a LONG time for `sudo systemctl restart ntopng` to return the prompt...  almost two minutes.